# An identity for Grassmann Gaussian integrals

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, fermions, grassmann-numbers

Suppose, for each $i=1,...,N$, $\bar{\psi}_{i}$ and $\psi_{i}$ are Grassmann *vectors* with $n$ entries $\bar{\psi}_{i,1},...,\bar{\psi}_{i,n}$ and analogously for $\psi_{i}$. Let $d\mu_{C}(\bar{\psi},\psi)$ is a Gaussian Grassmann measure with density:
$$e^{-\sum_{i,j=1}^{N}\bar{\psi}_{i}^{T}C_{ij}^{-1}\psi_{j}}$$
where, for each $i,j$ the covariance $C_{ij}$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.

I want to evaluate an integral of the form:
$$\int d\mu_{C}(\bar{\psi},\psi)e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\bar{\psi}_{i}^{T}B\psi_{i}}$$
Of course I can replace:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\bar{\psi}_{i}^{T}B\psi_{i} = \sum_{i,j=1}^{N}\bar{\psi}_{i}^{T}B\delta_{ij}\psi_{j}$$

**Question:** With the above change, can I decompose the Berezin integral by a product
$$\prod_{i,j=1}^{N}\int d\mu_{C_{ij}}(\bar{\psi}_{i},\psi_{j})e^{-\bar{\psi}_{i}^{T}B\delta_{ij}\psi_{j}}$$
with $d\mu_{C_{ij}}(\bar{\psi}_{i},\psi_{j})$ has now density
$$e^{-\bar{\psi}_{i}^{T}C_{ij}^{-1}\psi_{j}}?$$